# Select rows after certain value in a single row partitioned by id

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query that outputs the following table;

```
user_id   |   timestamp |   value
----------------------------------
123-456      2023-01-02    open
123-456      2023-01-03    open
123-456      2023-01-05    Begin
123-456      2023-01-07    open
123-456      2023-01-09    solved
123-456      2023-01-11    open
123-456      2023-01-13    solved
234-567      2023-01-04    Begin
234-567      2023-01-05    open
234-567      2023-01-07    open
234-567      2023-01-13    solved
```

Where I'm struggling is to get from here to what the table should look like. Basically, I want the first value for each user_id to be Begin, then the timestamps with individual open -> solved pairs. In other words, after the "Begin" value, I want the first open, then the next solved, then the next open, etc. The next column is "Rank," which should just be a dense_rank partitioned by user_id. The Rank column can be more than 2, I just have it here for illustrative purposes.

```
user_id   |   timestamp |   value  | Rank
--------------------------------------------
123-456      2023-01-05    Begin      1
123-456      2023-01-07    open       1
123-456      2023-01-09    solved     1
123-456      2023-01-11    open       2
123-456      2023-01-13    solved     2
234-567      2023-01-04    Begin      1
234-567      2023-01-05    open       1
234-567      2023-01-13    solved     1
```

I think its something like this:

```
Select user_id, 
first_value(timestamp over (partition by user_id, value order by timestamp asc),
dense_rank() over (partition by value,user_id) 
from table_1
```

But I'm honestly not sure. Any thoughts or help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a `QUALIFY` clause, that will get all records that:

- are not found before the first Begin
- have value either 'begin' or 'solved'
- (have value 'open' and) preceding value is not 'open'

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
QUALIFY SUM(value_='Begin') OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY timestamp_) > 0 
    AND (value_ IN ('Begin', 'solved') 
      OR NOT LAG(value_) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id 
                              ORDER     BY timestamp_) = 'open')
    )
```

Assumption is that only 'open' can be repeated in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example (tested on SQL Server)

```
with groupped as (
select * 
  ,sum(case when value='Begin' then 1 else 0 end)
      over(partition by user_id order by timestamp) beginN
  ,case when value='Begin' then 1 when value='open' then 2
        when value='solved' then 3
   else 4
   end operOrder
from test
)
,ranked as (
select * 
  ,row_number()over(partition by user_id,beginN,value order by timestamp) rnkOper
  ,count(case when value='open' then 1 end)
       over(partition by user_id,beginN) cntOpen
  ,count(case when value='solved' then 1 end)
       over(partition by user_id,beginN) cntSolved
from groupped
where beginN>0 -- only records after first 'Begin' for user_id
)
select * 
from ranked
where rnkOper<=cntSolved   -- else is open and not solved
order by user_id,beginN,rnkOper,operOrder
```